# windows ".lnk" shortcuts and batches don't mix

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error, shortcut

I have a batch file which is used by dragging a folder containing .mp3s into the batch.

```
@echo off
cd %~dp0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set FLDR="%1"
if not defined FLDR ( echo Drag a folder to the batch to play its contents.
pause
goto:EOF )
for %%x in (%FLDR%\*.mp3) do set "MP3=!MP3! "%%x""
mp3player %MP3%
pause
```

It works fine with actual folders, but when dragging shortcuts, the variable %FLDR% ends up as "c:\link location\folder.lnk" instead of the actual folder location.
I have no idea how to get around this.

Comment: `lnk` files aren't accessible by batch. If you start a folder link it opens an explorer window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a way to get the target using a little hybrid VBS/Batch file function.

```
@echo off   
setlocal

Call :GetTarget "%~1" tgt 
echo %tgt%
pause
exit /b 


:GetTarget  
@echo off & setlocal
set gt=%temp%\_.vbs
echo set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>%gt%
echo set Lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))>>%gt%
echo wscript.Echo Lnk.TargetPath>>%gt%
set script=cscript //nologo %gt%
For /f "delims=" %%a in ( '%script% "%~1"' ) do set target=%%a
del %gt%
endlocal & set %~2=%target%
exit /b
```

Comment: Idea is resolve shortcuts, not create! (I will not give you -1 to keep your perfect score!!!)

Comment: @LS_Dev Did you actually try the code? If so, you'll see that it doesn't create anything. It just uses the createshortcut method of the wscript.shell object to resolve the link target.

Comment: Ups... I've been hanging around looking for a method to open a link and didn't realize `CreateShortcut` ["Creates a new shortcut, or opens an existing shortcut"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6k3ys.aspx)... My apologizes!

Answer (score 1):

HYBRID SCRIPT! No silly little temporary files.

```
::'<SUB>@echo off
::'<SUB>set shortcut=%~1
::'<SUB>if not defined shortcut goto 'usage
::'<SUB>if not %shortcut:~-4%==.lnk (if not %shortcut:~-4%==.url (set errorlevel=1
::'<SUB>goto 'usage ))
::'<SUB>if not exist %shortcut% (echo Error: Nonexistent shortcut
::'<SUB>set errorlevel=1
::'<SUB>goto:EOF )
::'<SUB>setlocal
::'<SUB>for /f "delims=" %%T in ('cscript //nologo //e:vbs %~nx0 "%shortcut%"') do set thing=%%T
::'<SUB>endlocal & set shortcut=%thing%
::'<SUB>goto:EOF
:'usage
::'<SUB>echo command-line shortcut redirect utility
::'<SUB>echo Usage: shortcut [file.lnk ^| file.url]
::'<SUB>echo The resulting link will be output to the %%shortcut%% variable.
::'<SUB>goto:EOF
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set Lnk = WshShell.CreateShortcut(WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0))
wscript.Echo Lnk.TargetPath
```

Where `<SUB>` indicates the [substitute character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I found a much fully vbscript solution over at [Wayne's World of IT](http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/reading-shortcuts-with-powershell-and.html), and modified it slightly to suit my needs:

```
If WScript.Arguments.UnNamed.Count = 1 Then
 strShortcut = WScript.Arguments.UnNamed(0)
Else
 WScript.Echo "Please supply the name of an lnk file or directory to read, eg c:\test.lnk or c:\shortcuts"
 WScript.Quit(1)
End If
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists(strShortCut) Then
 Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(strShortcut)
 For Each objfile in objFolder.Files
  If objfile.type = "Shortcut" Then
   Call Readshortcut(objFile.Path, strProperties)
   dtmCreationDate = objFile.DateCreated
   WScript.Echo dtmCreationDate & "," & strProperties
  End If
 Next
ElseIf objFSO.FileExists(strShortCut) Then
 Call Readshortcut(strShortcut, strProperties)
 WScript.Echo strProperties
Else
 WScript.Echo "Error: Could not read '" & strShortcut & "'"
 WScript.Quit(2)
End If
Set objFSO = Nothing
Function Readshortcut(ByRef strShortcut, ByRef strProperties)
 set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 set objShellLink = objWshShell.CreateShortcut(strShortcut)
 strProperties = objShellLink.TargetPath & " " & objShellLink.Arguments
 Set objShellLink = Nothing
 Set objWshshell = Nothing
End Function
```