# Read from .lnk file and delete when necessary

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know if it's possible in batch to delete a .lnk file when meeting specific conditions.

For example, suppose I have the following file:
    %userprofile%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\Software.lnk
This link file actually points to C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe

Any .lnk file that points to calc.exe instead of software.exe, should be deleted.

If anyone has an idea, much appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no built-in command in cmd that could give you the target of a lnk. You'll have to use some kind of hybrid of batch and Powershell/VBS. This post should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653707/windows-lnk-shortcuts-and-batches-dont-mix

Comment: @MichaelS Ah, but [there is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27493262/1683264), if you count a WMI query via `wmic` as a built-in command.  Answer forthcoming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the target of a shortcut file with `wmic`.

```js
for %%I in (shortcut.lnk) do set "shortcut=%%~fI"
wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%shortcut:\=\\%'" get target /format:list | find "="
```

... will retrieve the target.  If all you want to do is take action if the target ends with `calc.exe`, just switch `find` for `findstr` and use conditional execution.

```js
for %%I in (shortcut.lnk) do set "shortcut=%%~fI"
wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%shortcut:\=\\%'" get target | findstr /i "\<calc.exe *$" && (
    del "%shortcut%"
)
```

If you want to loop through all shortcut files in a directory, just enclose the whole thing in a `for` loop and use delayed expansion.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for %%I in (*.lnk) do (
    rem // get full path of shortcut target
    set "target=%%~fI"

    rem // Because %target% was defined within this parenthetical code block,
    rem // you must use delayed expansion to retrieve it.

    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='!target:\=\\!'" get target | findstr /i "\<calc.exe *$" >NUL && (
        echo %%~nxI points to calc.exe.
        >>out.log echo Deleting %%~fI
        del "%%~fI"
    )
    endlocal
)
```

<sub>(`\<` is a word boundary in `findstr` regex.  The rest is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27493262/1683264).)</sub>

Comment: Very nice, thank you Rojo! I'm running in into 2 little problems:
1) I don't know the names of the shortcut file, so I tried with *.lnk, but it doesn't work.

2) I'd like to write out to a logfile if it deleted anything, so I appended >>out.log, but the logfile was empty...

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Rojo, I'm running into an issue. I want to incorporate your script into another script I'm using, but I'm getting this message several times
"No instance(s) available"

And nothing is deleted. The only thing different is that before your script I add "cd %AllUsersProfile%" and afterwards (after the last ")") I do another "setlocal enableextensions" as I need to delete other files as well. Any idea?

Comment: The `No instance(s) available` is a message produced from the `wmic` line when `"name='filename'"` does not match an existing path\\to\\file.  I'm guessing the `!target!` variable is getting clobbered before that line.  Try turning `echo on` and see if you can pinpoint when that happens.

Comment: Okay, so I tested. Indeed, if a directory does not exist I am getting that message. 

However, I tested on an existing directory with .lnk containing to calc and they were found but not deleted. Also, .lnk files NOT pointing to calc were found as if they were...

Comment: You ought to post your code in a new question.  Descriptions of what is in your script aren't as informative as actually seeing the script.  There might be a simple syntax or logic error somewhere.

Comment: Hi Rojo, thanks for your help so far. I posted a new topic here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692303/reading-from-lnk-and-deleting-not-functioning

Comment: Hi Rojo, I've posted a new topic. Do you have any idea what might go wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

check the [shortcutJS.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat) (it is a batch/jscript hybrid and should be saved with `.bat` extension)

you can use the `-examine` switch :

```
shortcutjs.bat -examine "C:\Users\user\Desktop\some.lnk"| find /i "calc.exe" &&(
    del /q /f "C:\Users\user\Desktop\some.lnk"
)
```