# Get "Start In" field using batch

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a program that looks at current plugged-in status, whether there's an external graphics card plugged in, and does a handful of things based on the results.

One of which, I am hoping to start programs using Shortcuts that are placed in one of a handful of folders.

This is all well and good. However, one of the programs that needs to be started also needs to have a .ini file replaced in the original location (e.g. C:\Folder\Shortcut.ini) at the time of startup.

SO. I need to get the "Start In" field (e.g. C:\Folder) from the shortcut/.lnk.

How would I go about doing this?

My google-fu is struggling here, because "start in" and "shortcut" all seem to lead to how to create a shortcut to start a batch file in a specific folder or to pass the location you run a batch file from to the program.

```
:StartPrograms
    if "%Mode%" EQU "Docked" for %%a in ("%RunPath%StartPrograms\Docked\*.lnk") do (start "" %%a)
    if "%Mode%" EQU "EGPU" for %%a in ("%RunPath%StartPrograms\EGPU\*.lnk") do (start "" %%a)
    if "%Mode%" EQU "Handheld" for %%a in ("%RunPath%StartPrograms\Handheld\*.lnk") do (start "" %%a)
    for %%a in ("%RunPath%StartPrograms\Always\*.lnk") do (start "" %%a)

    exit /b
```

[I want the "Start In" field here; or the full path of the shortcut as a string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8vjY.png)

Comment: Here's the google fu you need: [batch-file parse .ini file](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+parse+.ini+file)

Comment: @T3RR0R I have been able to parse .ini files plenty fine, but the methods I've used for those just seem to execute the .lnk when I try to target it with for /f

Answer (score 0):

You can call out to WMIC in a batch file as pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650022/1417694).

But you could also call out to Powershell as well within a batch file.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN (`"powershell $sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell; $sh.CreateShortcut('C:\Users\Public\Desktop\WinSCP.lnk').WorkingDirectory"`) DO @ECHO %%G
```

Comment: I will need to test this out, but the link you posted appears to have what I need. Thank you!